# Creating Fragments during orientation change

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-studio

I am following a book on Android programming and they are using some code to dynamically create Fragments whenever you change from portrait/landscape mode. However, portions of the example code is now deprecated, any ideas of how I would go about doing something similar to this?

```
FragmentTransaction frTr = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
WindowManager w = getWindowManager();
Display d = w.getDefaultDisplay();

if(d.getWidth() > d.getHeight())
    ......
else
    ....
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have to override `onConfigurationChanged` in your fragment or activity, for that try this code.

```
@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    setOrientation(newConfig.orientation);
}

/**
 * Set layout Orientation
 */
protected void setOrientation(int orientation) {

    if (orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE) {
   //write your code for ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE
    } else if (orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT) {
   //write your code for ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried this and used Ctrl+F11 to change orientation, but it doesn't seem to trigger onConfigurationChanged at all.

Comment: please add this line in your _AndroidManifest.xml_ for  _MainActivity_
`android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize|keyboard|keyboardHidden"`